# viewValue undefined in angular 4 select option

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have the following code in html,

```
 <mat-form-field>
   <mat-select placeholder="Choose location" (change)="onChange($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value">
      {{ option.viewValue }}
    </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

In ts file, i have the following onChange function,

```
public onChange(selected: any): void {
    console.log(selected.value);
    console.log(selected.viewValue);
  }
```

Array of options,

```
options= [
    {value: 1, viewValue: 'ABC'},
    {value: 2, viewValue: 'XYZ'},
    {value: 3, viewValue: 'PQR'}
  ];
```

But I do not see expected values in console.
When I click on ABC, following is printed on console,

> 1
>   undefined.

The second console output is undefined. I am expecting the second console output as "ABC" i.e corresponding viewValue.

Comment: `(change)` outputs the current value of the selected option. This would be `option.value`, not `option` itself. This is what you defined here `[value]="option.value"`.

Comment: @Silvermind, can you please help me, how to modify it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the value property of the event object:

Change your html to this:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Choose location" (change)="onChange($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
      {{ option.viewValue }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

And your ts to this:

```
public onChange(selected: any): void {
  const option = selected.value;
  console.log(option.value);
  console.log(option.viewValue);
}
```

Comment: can i create object for options and get the (change) output as the option object itself?

Comment: For the above answer, getting error as follows, `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'viewValue' of undefined`

Comment: @Anil Sorry. I have updated my answer. Long time since I worked with Angular Material Design.

Comment: i was trying to create an object for option. object class is like this, `export class Option{
    value: number;
    viewValue: string;
    constructor() {

    }
}` , i have bind this object in `<mat-select>` tag, and new onChange function is like this, `public onChange(optionSelected: Option): void {
    console.log(optionSelected.viewValue);` but the console output is **undefined**, can you please tell me where i am wrong?

Comment: Make sure you are passing `$event.value` in html. `onChange($event.value)`